# Ubuntu defaults to using Python3.5 instead of Python3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu

Ubuntu has Python 3.5.2 pre-installed. I'm trying to use Python 3.6 as my default, but many packages, particularly IPython, default to using Python 3.5.2 instead of Python3.6. As far as getting the 'Python3' command to work on Python 3.6 instead of 3.5, I tried doing a symlink that only ended up breaking my terminal since Linux seems to use Python 3.5 somewhere. I've settled for using an alias for Python3 in my `.bashrc` file, but how can I get my packages to default to using Python 3.6?

This is what happens when I run IPython (again, 3.6 is installed). I've attempted to upgraded IPython as well.

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

Comment: How did you install Python 3.6? From `apt-get` or somewhere else?

Comment: I installed using apt-get

Answer (score -1):

## What's going wrong?

The packages you installed yourself don't read your `.bashrc`, so they don't get that you added anything to your `.bashrc`.

You get system problems because Ubuntu relies on `python` to be some Python 2.7 and `python3` to be some Python 3.5. This is why symlinking globally is a bad idea.

I recommend you use a Python distribution preloaded with the tooling. I like Anaconda Python.

## Setting up Anaconda Python

You will have to do this for all the executables you want to use instead of the system defaults. For Python, this can be multiple things (`python`, `ipython`, `spyder`, and more).

To solve this for me, I use Anaconda Python, which bundles all the stuff you typically want, including `python`, `ipython`, Jupyter Notesbooks, Spyder, Numpy, Scipy, etc. If you want to do the same:

1. Install [Anaconda Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), choose the version you want
2. Add `PATH="/home/YOURUSERNAME/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` to your path, changing `YOURUSERNAME` to you actual user name.

This lets you call your preferred `python` executable. Here's how my system looks like (I use Python 2):

```
$ which python
/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/bin/python
$ which ipython
/home/teodorlu/anaconda2/bin/ipython
$ ls anaconda2/bin | grep python
activate-global-python-argcomplete
ipython
ipython2
python
python2
python2.7
python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
python-config
register-python-argcomplete
```

## Switching between different python versions with `conda`

Anaconda comes with an environment manager, which will ensure that when you type `python` or `ipython`, you get what you expect. Here's a start:

```
$ conda env --help
usage: conda-env [-h] {attach,create,export,list,remove,upload,update} ...

positional arguments:
  {attach,create,export,list,remove,upload,update}
    attach              Embeds information describing your conda environment
                        into the notebook metadata
    create              Create an environment based on an environment file
    export              Export a given environment
    list                List the Conda environments
    remove              Remove an environment
    upload              Upload an environment to anaconda.org
    update              Update the current environment based on environment
                        file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Seriously? Downvote and no details? I put some effort into this answer. If it is considered _personally insulting_ to suggest that the current approach is bad, that's an inappropriate attitude for a learning community.

Comment: just arriving, but the fact that this does not provide any example of how to actually use `conda` to setup a python 2/3 version might be a reason behind the downvote

Comment: @lurscher I think you're right. Re-reading this now old answer, I re-framed the question to "how can I use Python without hassle", without properly addressing the question text. Thanks!